# Kotlin, map a class to another class

Tags: kotlin

I'm creating an API rest and I need it when I do "find ALL" instead of fetching all the data, I just fetch a few. With Java I did it this way:

```
 @GetMapping(value = "/pagina")
    public ResponseEntity<Page<PersonFindDTO>> findAll(
            @RequestParam(value = "page", defaultValue = "0") Integer page,
            @RequestParam(value = "linesPerPage", defaultValue = "24") Integer linesPerPage,
            @RequestParam(value = "order", defaultValue = "ASC") String order,
            @RequestParam(value = "orderBy", defaultValue = "name") String orderBy) {


        var person = personService.findAll(page, linesPerPage, order, orderBy);

        var personFindDto = person.map(PersonFindDTO::new);

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(personFindDTO);
    }
```

With Kotlin, I'm trying this way:

```
   @GetMapping(value = ["/{companyId}/{active}"])
    override fun findAll(
            @RequestParam(value = "page", defaultValue = "0") page: Int,
            @RequestParam(value = "linesPerPage", defaultValue = "24") linesPerPage: Int,
            @RequestParam(value = "order", defaultValue = "ASC") order: String,
            @RequestParam(value = "orderBy", defaultValue = "tradeName") orderBy: String,
            @PathVariable companyId: Long, @PathVariable active: Boolean): ResponseEntity<Page<Any>> {

        val lp = service.findAll(page, linesPerPage, order, orderBy, companyId, active)?.let {
            it.map {
                fun LegalPerson.toLegalPersonMPage() = LegalPersonMPage(id = it.id,
                        tradeName = it.tradeName, companyName = it.companyName, cnpj = it.cnpj)
            }
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(lp)
    }
```

But the return is always empty. Could anyone help? Please.

UPDATE:

My LegalPerson Class

```
data class LegalPerson(
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  override var id: Long,
  @Column(nullable = false)
  val companyId: Long,
  @Column(nullable = false)
  var active: Boolean,
  @Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
  val tradeName: String,
  @Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
  val companyName: String,
  @Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
  val email: String,
  @Column(nullable = false, length = 18)
  val cnpj: String,
  @Column(length = 15)
  val stateRegistration: String,
  @Column(length = 15)
  val municipalRegistration: String,
  @Column(nullable = false)
  val openingDate: LocalDate,
  @Column(nullable = false)
  val address: Long,
  @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @CollectionTable(name = "phone", schema = "legal_person")
  val phones: List<Long>
)
```

My LegalPersonMPage class

```
data class LegalPersonMPage(

        val id: Long,
        val tradeName: String,
        val companyName: String,
        val cnpj: String
)  {
}
```

Comment: Why Any instead of PersonFindDTO?

Comment: I tried both and without success.
I'll update my question. Just a moment

Comment: Try `it.map { LegalPersonMPage(id = it.id, tradeName = it.tradeName, companyName = it.companyName, cnpj = it.cnpj) }`. You are just defining a function inside `map`, but you are not calling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `LegalPerson.toLegalPersonMPage()` is defined but never called. To make this clearer define the function outside of `map {...}` and call it inside of `map {...}`.

```
fun LegalPerson.toLegalPersonMPage() = LegalPersonMPage(id = this.id,
    tradeName = this.tradeName, companyName = this.companyName, cnpj = this.cnpj)


@GetMapping(value = ["/{companyId}/{active}"])
override fun findAll(
    @RequestParam(value = "page", defaultValue = "0") page: Int,
    @RequestParam(value = "linesPerPage", defaultValue = "24") linesPerPage: Int,
    @RequestParam(value = "order", defaultValue = "ASC") order: String,
    @RequestParam(value = "orderBy", defaultValue = "tradeName") orderBy: String,
    @PathVariable companyId: Long, @PathVariable active: Boolean): ResponseEntity<Page<Any>> {

    val lp = service.findAll(page, linesPerPage, order, orderBy, companyId, active)?.let {
        it.map { legalPerson -> legalPerson.toLegalPersonMPage() }
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(lp)
}
```

Comment: `it` is undefined in `toLegalPersonMPage`. Do you mean `this`?